# How to styling header & button with StyleProvider at the same page?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I've struggling for two days to styling components on Native Base with `<StyleProvider>`. I want to change background color of header and add custom style property on the button.

```
<Container>
    <Header /> /*change backgroundColor*/
    <Content>
        <Button viewDetail block> /*add 'viewDetail' as custom style property */
            <Text>Button</Text>
        </Button>
    </Content>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, I have the answer for my own question.
Import all components from 'native-base-theme/components/' instead of variables.

The code will be like this

```
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
```

and add `<StyleProvider>`, then add prop style `<StyleProvider style={getTheme()}>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. One way would be to follow the instructions given [here](http://nativebase.io/docs/v2.0.0/customize#themeyours). Alternatively, you can change the button theme file and add a similar style property like [success shown here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/components/Button.js#L56).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, 
You must be using NativeBase2

```
<StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>
  <Header>
    <Left>
      <Button transparent>
        <Icon name="arrow-back" onPress={() => this.props.routerActions.pop()} />
      </Button>
    </Left>
    <Body>
      <Title>Profile</Title>
    </Body>
    <Right></Right>
  </Header>
 </StyleProvider>
```

For ejecting theme,
Just open this link and follow
http://nativebase.io/docs/v2.0.0/customize#themingNativeBaseApp

Now If you want to customise just look for

`native-base-theme/components/Header.js`

`native-base-theme/variables/commonColor.js`